# Matrices in R Programming

Tags: r, matrix

I am new to R programming, and I have few questions regarding matrices in R.

I have a function that returns a matrix. I want to check if the returned matrix is empty or not. How do I check it in R? If it is an integer, we can check it by `is.null(someinteger)`. But how do we check the same in the case of matrices?

Also, an integer can be initialized by `x <- NULL`. If I have just wanted to initialize a matrix. Do we initialize like `mat <- matrix()` or is there any other way? `mat` can be of any size.

Answer (score 2):

There is some question of what is meant by "empty" here but this will test if matrix `m` has zero length:

```
length(m) == 0
```

Regarding initializing a matrix this initializes it to be a 0x0 matrix:

```
m <- matrix(, 0, 0)
```

and this initalizes it to be a 1x1 matrix containing NA:

```
m <- matrix()
```

and this initializes it to an `nr` by `nc` matrix of NA values:

```
m <- matrix(, nr, nc)
```

Not clear whether any of these are actually useful.  You may want to describe what you are trying to accomplish.  Why do you need to initialize it at all?

Comment: By checking if a matrix is null, i mean if the matrix returned has all NA values or not. Regarding the initialization, i am trying to declare a variable which is a matrix. So i was wondering how do it do it. If its a vector x <- c() and integer x <- 0 something like that can be done.

Comment: I think we understand that you are trying to initialize a variable to a matrix but why?  Are you trying to subsequently fill it element by element?  Normally if you can avoid it then it's better not to use such an approach but rather it is best when possible to create objects using the whole object approach.  More detail is required to say anything more meaningful for your particular circumstance.

Comment: I want to declare a variable which is a matrix type but the size of it is not known. it is later set to the output of a  function, which returns a matrix.

Comment: If `f` is the function whiose output is a matrix just write `m <- f()`.  `m` does not need to exist prior to that.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
all(is.na(m))
```

Or:

```
is.logical(m)
```

Can act as a single function test. If one `numeric` or `character` is an element of the list, it will return `FALSE`. The second solution should work; it appears that your function is creating matrices with numbers and/or NAs.